# Loopback allowing all users to access something that only the owner should see

Tags: javascript, acl, loopbackjs, loopback

In my loopback app I have two models: `user` and `thing`.

Basically `thing` belongs to `user` and only the owner can access `thing`. This is what my `thing.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "thing",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId",
      "primaryKey": "id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

What is happening is if I deny everyone like I am doing now before allowing certain roles, no one is allowed to access or create things, but if I remove that line all users are able to access all things. Did I miss something? I would like just the owner to be able to access their own things.

Thanks!

Comment: Try launching your server `DEBUG=loopback:security:* node . ` (linux & macos) or `set DEBUG=loopback:security:*  & node .` (windows) to see how loopback is deciding who gets access.

Comment: Thanks will sure help a lot! However, I am not quite sure how to interpret  this for this particular case. It seems like perhaps the user isn't being recognized as the owner? In the ACL log, I am getting that the principalId is `$everyone`, which is why I am being denied. But how in the world do I set the current user as the one allowed to create and see their own `things`?

Comment: Can you send the url you're trying to use to mutate `things`?  Loopback resolves the user (and if you're an owner or not) by looking at your `access_token`

Comment: Here is the API call I am using to get `things`: `axios.get('localhost:3002/challenges', {params: { access_token: user.id}})`.
So basically, `localhost:3002/challenges?access_token="[MY TOKEN]"`

Comment: You're not specifying the id of what you're getting.  Antonio's answer is correct.  You want `axios.get('localhost:3002/challenges/' + TheIdOfTheChallengeIWant, {params: {access:token: user.id}})`.

Comment: Ahh! I see. I focused mainly on the setup part talking about the belongTo relation. But in that case, how would I grab all challenges? Also, for safety reasons how could I prevent other users from accessing other `challenges`? PS: `things`===`challenges` I forgot to replace them in the URLs, my bad!

Comment: See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Accessing-related-models.html#restricting-access-to-related-models.  TLDR You need to create a `hasMany` relation on `Users` to `challenges`, then you'll be able to query it with `/users/{id}/challenges` in the same way the default user model can query its access tokens with `/api/Users/{id}/accessTokens`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Loopback [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html)

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo relation to the User model (or a model that extends User) and property matching the foreign key of the target model instance.  The check for $owner is performed only for a remote method that has ‘:id’ on the path, for example, GET /api/users/:id.

Comment: From my understanding, that is exactly what I am doing in my current code. If not, what have I missed?
I have also looked through the BelongsTo relation (found here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/BelongsTo-relations.html#defining-a-belongsto-relation), and I don't see what was missed.

Comment: Are you calling `/api/users/:id/things` or `/api/users/:id/things/:fk`? Value for the property `model` should be `User` (capitalized).

Comment: This was indeed my initial problem, though there were a few more such as never disabling the `User` model. But I had a big misunderstanding when it came to the relationships between my models and this was the main thing.

Thanks!